# How to refresh webelement on blur-event call (Angular 2, Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular

I am writing an app with an html site on which the user writes an Url into a text-field and when leaving said text field, he gets to choose something from a list that got extracted from said URL.

The extraction works just fine, but the selection of the listitems won't update.
Therefor, how can I refresh/reload/update a certain webelement (be it the div or the select) in an on-blur event call?

As a further explaination:

I have an html that looks somewhat like this:

```
<div><input (blur)="onBlurCall($event)" [(ng-model)]="x.url"></div>

<div>
    <select [(ng-model)]="x.extractedElement">
        <option *ng-for="#l of extractedList" value="{{ l.name }}">
            {{ l.label }}
        </option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Now what I want is:
The User loads the site. No Url in the input element is defined yet, so the select loads a default value -> that works.

Then the User enters an Url in the input element and clicks out of it, thus calling the blur function. From the Url, a list of items is extracted -> also works (I console-logged the list right after the blur call).

Now the select element should update to show the recently extracted list and let the User select an element of it -> not working, as it still shows the default value.
What the connected .ts file does should not be much of an issue here, but if needed I can provide information about it as well.

Script parts referably in typescript, as that is what I am using (and I am not fluent enough to translate js to ts).

as requested, parts of the ts file:

```
export class configuration {

// bunch of variables
public extractedList: Array<listItem>;

constructor() {
    // other initlializations
    this.config = DataContainer.Config; // contains url variable
    var l= new listItem();
    //console.log('default list being build');
    l.Label = 'Please enter the local Url first';
    l.Url = '';
    l.Name = 'default l';
    this.extractedList= [l]; 
    //console.log('default list name: ' + l.Name);
}

  public onLocalUrlBlur(event) {
    //console.log('Blur call');
    this.otherService.getExtractedList(this.config.localUrl, this.setExtractedList, this.getExtractedListError);
    // calls external service to extract the list 
  }

  public setExtractedList(listData) {
    //console.log('set list ' + listData);
    this.extractedList= listData;
    //console.log('new list first label: ' + this.extractedList[0].Label);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please post the component code as well, specifically the `onBlurCall` event and also the initialization whether that be the constructor or some sort of init function.

Comment: edited my original post. If I'm not mistaken, that should be all relevant parts of the ts-file, since, as I said, setting the extracted list itself works (in the test case here, just a 1-element list, the last console log in `setExtractedList` gives the right label). just the `<select>` element on the html never updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok what is happening is that since you are passing the method `this.setExtractedList` in as a callback to `getExtractedList` it is being executed in a different context, so you will need to bind that callback to the context/scope of your class like this:

```
this.otherService.getExtractedList(
  this.config.localUrl,
  this.setExtractedList.bind(this),
  this.getExtractedListError);
```

Another way to accomplish this is by explicitly using a fat-arrow function:

```
this.otherService.getExtractedList(
  this.config.localUrl,
  (listData)  => { this.setExtractedList(listData) },
  this.getExtractedListError);
```

Comment: tried the fat-arrow function first, works like a charm! thanks a lot =)